# Dropbox UIDocumentPicker plugin cannot open OS X file packages

Tags: ios, dropbox, cloudkit, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc

On my OS X machine I have placed a document which actually is a [file package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_(OS_X)) (aka document bundle) into my dropbox. When I try to open that file package on my iOS device using the UIDpocumentPicker plugin the file package appears as a folder. On the other hand it appears as a file package in the iOS DropBox App itself. It also appears as a file in iCloud drive.

Why is there a different behavior? I would expect both dropbox interfaces to display the file package as a file and be able to open it like I can open out from iCloud drive.
(Dropbox App-Version 4.2.5 on iOS 9.2)

Anyone else having this issue and any idea on what one could do?

Answer (score 1):

Packages are effectively folders, not files. Different interfaces may not display them the same way though. E.g., sometimes you'll see a special icon indicating it's a package, and sometimes just the normal folder icon will be used.

In any case, packages/folders aren't currently supported in the Dropbox iOS app UIDocumentPicker. We'll consider this a feature request though.

Comment: Thank you for considering this as a future request. This still does not explain why dropbox supports document bundles in the Dropbox iOS app but not in the Dropbox UIDocument Picker interface. This doesn't make any sense and — honestly — looks more like a bug.